# Open the file in python only once

Tags: python

I have the `Parse` class (`parse.py`) whose role is to parse an event according to some patterns in the `patterns.txt` file.

```
class Parse:

   def __init__(self, log ): 
     self.log = log


   def parse(self):
     parsed_log = ""
     for pattern in patterns:
        grok = Grok(pattern)
        result = grok.match(self.log)
        if result:
           parsed_log = result
        break
    return parsed_log



def main(log):
   patterns = open('patterns.txt', 'r')
   matches = Parse(log)
   parsed_log = matches.parse()
```

The above script (`parse.py`) will be called by another module in order to parse multiple logs, for example:

```
import parse
for log in a logs
    parse.main(log)
```

The main will be called a lot of times which means that the "patterns.txt" file will be opened for every call. What I want to do is to open the file only once in order to avoid opening it for every call. How can I achieve this? I would really appreciate if someone would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Parse.parse` should not depend on a global file handle. Open it once *before* the loop, but remember to reseek to the beginning at the start of each iteration.

```
class Parse:

   def __init__(self, log ): 
     self.log = log


   def parse(self, patterns):
     parsed_log = ""
     for pattern in patterns:
        grok = Grok(pattern)
        result = grok.match(self.log)
        if result:
           parsed_log = result
        break
    return parsed_log


def main(log, patterns):
    matches = Parse(log)
    parsed_log = matches.parse(patterns)
```

Then

```
import parse

with open('patterns.txt') as f:
    for log in log:
        f.seek(0)
        parse.main(log, f)
```

Comment: thank you! When you're saying "Parse.parse should not depend on a global file handle." why is that? What is the problem with the file as a global variable?

Comment: Because your class has no control over who or what can modify the global, and cannot ensure that `patterns` has even been defined before you call `Parse.parse`. (True, you could use `global patterns` and define it yourself, but then at that point, why make it global anyway?)

Answer (score 0):

You could open the file within the `other` module, like this:

```
import parse

patterns = open('patterns.txt', 'r')
for log in a logs
    parse.main(log, patterns)
```

and within `parse.py`:

```
def main(log, patterns):
   matches = Parse(log)
   parsed_log = matches.parse(patterns)
```

Or even better, include the file opening as part of the constructor, and reuse the same object for each `log` you process.

Answer (score 0):

To open the file once after importing the module
You must open the file outside the function.

```
patterns = open('patterns.txt', 'r')

def main(log):   
   matches = Parse(log)
   parsed_log = matches.parse()
```

Comment: If I open it globally, where do I close it?

Comment: @user1234 like this `parse.patterns.close()`